# std::shared_ptr lost between std::function callbacks

Tags: c++, asynchronous, std

I have the following async task implementation

```
template <class T>
class async_task {

public:
    ptr<progress_status> do_async(std::function<void(ptr<T>)> on_success, std::function<void(ptr<progress_status>)> on_failure);

protected:
    virtual void do_async_tick() = 0;

    ptr<progress_status> status = nullptr;
    ptr<T> result = nullptr;
};

template<class T>
inline ptr<progress_status> async_task<T>::do_async(std::function<void(ptr<T>)> on_success, std::function<void(ptr<progress_status>)> on_failure)
{
    status = alloc<progress_status>();
    std::async(std::launch::async, [&, this] {
        
        do {
            try {
                do_async_tick();
            }
            catch (std::exception& e) {
                status->error = alloc<std::string>(e.what());
            }
        } while (status->error != nullptr && result != nullptr);

        if (status->error != nullptr)
            on_failure(status);
        else {
            status->progress = 1.f;
            on_success(result);
        }
    });

    return status;
}
```

I implement this class to use it to load some textures

```
class texture_loader_async : public async_task<std::vector<std::pair<std::string, ptr<dx_texture>>>> {
public:
    virtual void do_async_tick() override;
};

class textures : public resource_bag<dx_texture>, public singleton<textures>
{
    friend class singleton<textures>;
public:
    virtual ptr<progress_status> load(std::function<void()> on_success, std::function<void()> on_failure) override;

private:
    texture_loader_async loader;
};
```

With the implementation

```
ptr<progress_status> textures::load(std::function<void()> on_success, std::function<void()> on_failure)
{
    return loader.do_async(
        [&](auto textures) {
            for (auto& pair : *textures) {
                add_resource(pair.first.c_str(), pair.second);
            }
            on_success();
        },
        [&](auto status) {
            on_failure();
        }
    );
}
```

Here `ptr` = `std::shared_ptr` and `alloc` = `std::make_shared`

My problem is that the async task result that comes in the on_success event in textures::load is null, even though that shouldnt be possible
Basically in async_task::do_async the while ends because of the result != nullptr and somewhere along the way its lost and it sends nullptr to on_success...

Comment: this is simpler if you show the code instead of describing it. "Here ptr = std::shared_ptr " -> `using ptr = std::shared_ptr`. Also the code you posted is just some class definitions and  functions. Can you show a small `main` where the functions are called ([mcve])?

Comment: `[&]` captures by reference. When you use it to capture arguments in the scope of the calling functions those objects stop existing at the end of calling function. or example, For example, `[&](auto status)` should be `[on_failure](auto status)` or `[=](auto status)` for the lazy.

Answer (score 2):

`[&]` captures by reference.  Never use `[&]` unless the resulting lambda and all copies will be destroyed before the end of the current scope.

You pass it to `do_async`, which seems unlikely to destroy the lambdas (and all copies of them) by the end of your current scope.

So your code follows dangling references.

The easy change is to change to `[=]`; but really, when you are doing async work, **explicitly list all of your captures**.  I'd even advise against capturing `this`.

Of course, in the body of the function, you call `std::async` and discard the result, which blocks immediately until the async task finishes.  So there is that.  But if you fixed the problem you'd run into your reference capture issue.

I'd suspect that your code isn't a minimal complete verifiable example, and other stuff is going on.

The `status->error` code is also bad code smell.  There doesn't seem to be any synchronization between the async code and the main thread there (I mean, maybe you have an insane `operator->` overload, but I doubt it).

Answer (score 0):

Although there were already issues with lambda captures and blocking async (thank you for pointing that to me), the main issue that was causing the bug was a reversed while condition...

```
while (status->error != nullptr && result != nullptr);
```

to

```
while (status->error == nullptr && result == nullptr);
```